# Trying to serve a static txt file while using MERN stack

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, react-router, mern

Im using the MERN stack + Heroku to deploy and want to host a static txt file at "myurl.com/file.txt".

My file.txt is in the client/build directory.

When I navigate to "myurl.com/file.txt" I get "Cannot GET /file.txt"

I know this is probably a newby question and a bit open ended, I have looked a bunch online but I'm struggling to figure this out. Thanks in advance!

Here is a code snippet of my server.js file.

If there is any other info you need pls ask!

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = "my_mongodb_uri"; // of course here I have my actual URI, I know its not secure, I'll change it before it goes public :P
mongoose.connect(uri, { useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
        .then(connect => console.log('connected to mongodb'))
        .catch(e => console.log('could not connect to mongodb', e))

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => { console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully"); })

const matchesRouter = require('./routes/matches');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/matches', matchesRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
}

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`)
});
```

Comment: I think you haven't really serve the file anywhere in your server entry point file?
so the thing is you want to the serve text file, any text file that's located inside build folder which is the same level as the index.js
you need to add another endpoint, and send the respond with ```respond.sendFile(filename.txt)``` as for the mime-type text/plain is suffice.

Comment: Can you provide router files because i dont see any routes that actually serve the text file  as mentioned by @Barack Obama

Comment: you don't really need a router file, here's an example

```app.get("/textfile", (_req, res) => {
  res.status(200).sendFile("./file.txt");
});```

here's reference to the docs
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

edit:
oh, I beg you pardon, misunderstood the comment! it wasn't from him.

Comment: So I added this and it worked!
Thanks!

`app.get('/file', (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/build/file.txt')); });`